# Lorentz force, multiple conductors?

Tags: electromagnetism

3 conductors are placed in a magnetic field $B$, that have equal current $I$ flowing, is the Lorentz force totaled as the sum of all those conductors? Assuming that all of them have the same direction of current.

Comment: The question could be more specific.  Is the force in question, the total force exerted by the $B$ field, or the force on each of the wires due to the $B$ field as well as the current in the other two wires?

Comment: Only the force exerted by B on the wires, without including the attractive/repulsive forces created by the current flowing in the two wires. However, since your reminded me of a key concept I missed, the current flowing on each wire, since they are near each other would induce small EMF correct? And about the forces that attracts/repels the wires what formula is best to calculate it?

Comment: Figured it out, the force of each wire would be: F = I(wire[1])B(of wire [2])L(wire[1]... or am I wrong?

Comment: I'll try to put the correct formula in an answer below if I get the time since we're apparently not supposed to answer questions here.  In the mean time, you can look up the formula you want between wires on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if they are placed parallel, and the magnetic field is constant in space, and their current is also the same. The formula is:

$$\mathbf{F} = I\int \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\ell}\times \mathbf{B}$$

Yes, the sum of a force is the vectoric sum of its components, and it is so even if there is a different current (and thus, different forces).

Comment: Even if they have different values of current?

Comment: @Key Yes, I extended my answer.